# Redirect to and back from an external URL

Tags: angular

Starter code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dknvcc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**TLDR:** Clicking the "Authorize" button in ^app takes you to Microsoft login page, which takes you to a URL containing an access token (image attached). How do I grab the token from that URL and return back to the original app?

In this app, when you click on the "Authorize" button, it takes you to a Microsoft login page on the same tab/window by doing `this.document.location.href = url;` (well not really, because the URL in the starter code is fake for security reasons). We are logging in to authorize the above app using the OAuth2 scheme so that we can access an external REST API.

The act of logging in with email and password redirects you to a new URL which contains the access token, expiration period of access and other details in it (FYI, the redirect URL's localhost and port can be found in the fake URL). Please see the attached image below to see what that redirect page and URL looks like. I need the access token and the expiration period from that URL to access resources in the external API.

**Question:** How do I grab that token from that redirect URL, save it in the session storage, and return back to my original app page?

(If it is relevant, in the real app, the user is required to Log in with internal credentials in order to access the "Authorize" button's page. If possible, I would like to avoid logging in again with internal credentials. Just grab the the access token and expiration period and redirect to the Authorize button page without needing to re-login)

[The page after redirecting to URL containing the access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrCvF.png)

Comment: Have you considered to use Microsoft MSAL for Angular? I am not sure if it mets your requirements, but I am working with it and it does the job.

Comment: I have,but it was a pain to build the Auth URL using that library; IDK how to pass some of the parameters in the URL (^please refer to the stackblitz link), like 'response_type' &  'scope'. I tried to follow the tutorial below without passing in those parameters, and that took me as far as the login page & after that, it redirected to the same error page as shown in the image in the description (but I think it was missing the access token in the URL). If u can help with this, that would be awesome.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code

Answer (score 0):

In the flow I've implemented before, the user would get redirected to the Microsoft login page and after logging in, the user is redirected back to the root of your application passing the code as a parameter. It normally comes back with a code and you need to use that to get a token by calling an API but if you get the access token back (which I find it odd) then it's probably easier.

What you would need to do is to read the location and check if there is a parameter passed. In your image the page back doesn't look right, rather than being

`http://localhost:4001/#access_token=......`

I'd expect it to come back to the app with

`http://localhost:4001/?access_token=......`

with that, you can put code in the constructor of your main component in the app to read the code and store it in the session storage (probably in memory is better).

Once you get the token, you can redirect the user to the main route of your app where you would probably start making API calls, you should use HTTP Interceptors to add the token from the session storage to each call (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)

Look at this fork I did from your stackblitz, I also put an image below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e6qjyz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

You'll also need to keep checking the token expires or get a 401 response, etc., you can do all that with HTTP interceptors as I mentioned before

Best option is to find a library that handles this for you otherwise you'll need to implement all these steps in your app

[image]

Comment: 1) I don't have my work PC with me right now, but I am concerned this may not work since the user is redirected to an external website (outside of my Angular app's control). Let me know if I am wrong in this assumption.

2) "Once you get the token, you can redirect the user to the main route of your app" - is that by setting window.location.href to the original page's URL?

Comment: 1) that's standard in the authentication flow, you get redirected to a website where you enter user name/password and then redirected back to the route of your application
2) yes, you can set window location, maybe to "/home". There is also a scenario where the user navigates directly to one of the routes in your app, you want to go back to that specific route, you could set that route in the local session before the user is sent to the login page